# I need to execute a Curl script on Jenkins so as to check the status URL

Tags: shell, curl, jenkins

The script should check for Http status code for the URL and should show error when status code doesn't match for eg. 200.
In Jenkins if this script fails then Build should get failed and Mail is triggered through post build Procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use simple shell command as referred in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/442395)

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://www.example.org/
```

Comment: I want to check http code and if it is other than 200 then it should show some message or exit.

Comment: You can use this code in any shell script. It returns response http code of the request.

Answer (score 9):

Another interesting feature of `curl` is its `-f`/`--fail` option. If set, it will tell `curl` to fail on any HTTP error, i.e. `curl` will have an exit code different from 0, if the server response status code was not 1xx/2xx/3xx, i.e. if it was 4xx or above, so

```
curl --silent --fail "http://www.example.org/" >/dev/null
```

or (equivalently):

```
curl -sf "http://www.example.org/" >/dev/null
```

would have an exit code of 22 rather than 0, if the URL could not be found or if some other HTTP error occurred. See `man curl` for a description of `curl`'s various exit codes.

Comment: important caveat in the man page:


"This method is not fail-safe and there are occasions where  non-successful  response  codes  will  slip
              through, especially when authentication is involved (response codes 401 and 407)."

Comment: although from my experience just now, 401 are not always a problem. In my case it failed correctly even for a 401

Answer (score 5):

This will happen if the following shell script is added:

```
response=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n" http://www.example.org/)
if [ "$response" != "200" ]
then
 exit 1
fi
```

`exit 1` will mark build as failed

Answer (score 3):

Jenkins also has [HTTP Request Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin) that can trigger HTTP requests.

For example this is how you can check response status and content:

```
def response = httpRequest "http://httpbin.org/response-headers?param1=${param1}"
println('Status: '+response.status)
println('Response: '+response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
response=`curl -k -s -X GET --url "<url_of_the_request>"`
echo "${response}"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about passing the URL at run time using curl in bashscript
URL=www.google.com
"`curl --location --request GET URL`"

How we can pass url at runtime ?